# How can I set a project's "browse permission" after I emptied the "browse permission" of the project?

Tags: permissions, jira

**Background**:

- I'm Jira admin.
- We use Jira Server 7.8.4

**The Problem**:

I was trying to set one of our project's "browse permission", but I removed all the users/groups/roles at first. That's the problem -- Since the "browse permission" was completely removed, nobody can see this project, including me.

I can see the "audit log" and clearly see that was me clear the "browse permission".

Please advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may always as a jira-administrator see all projects from the admin project view even if you dont have permission

Click on the admin cog -> projects

Jira will display all projects even if you dont have permission to browse (because you still have permission to administer)

Regards,

Comment: Thanks, that helps. I didn't check the admin cog > projects page before.